# What are the NPC fetch quests in Pokemon Sun / Moon?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

A number of NPCs in Pokemon Sun & Moon ask me to do an errand then return.  For example, I have met a scientist who wanted to me to return to him when I'd attained ten Pokemon 'caught' Pokedex entries.

The game doesn't seem to list these quests anywhere, so it's hard to remember what I've been asked to do (and where to go back to turn it in when I have done so).

How many of these people are there, where are they, and what are they after?

Comment: A lot of them seem to be Pokedex-related i.e. 'I'm interested in seeing 'X' Pokemon, can you catch one and show me your Pokedex" etc

Comment: There is no in-game list of quests if that's what you're looking for. You just have to write it down and do it the old school way of keeping track.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I haven't beaten the game yet, but here's the list of ones I have encountered so far.

Melemele Island:

- Route 2 Pokemon Center - girl with hat - Cutiefly
- Route 3 - male sightseer - Rockruff
- Hau’oli City Tourist Bureau - scientist - register 10 Pokemon species in your Pokedex
- Hau’oli City Pokemon Center - blonde woman - Drifloon

Akala Island:

- Heahea City clothing store - man - Pyukumuku
- Route 5 Pokemon Center - scientist - Feebas
- Route 8 Aether Foundation trailer - Aether employee - Stufful
- Konikoni City Pokemon Center - Aether employee - Oranguru/Passimian

Ula’ula Island:

- Malie City clothing store - collector - Togedemaru
- Malie City Library - Samson Oak - Alolan Persian (must have the Persian in your party for this quest)
- Route 16 Pokemon Center - Aether employee - Mimikyu

Poni Island:

- Seafolk Village - woman in Steelix boat - Alolan Raichu

Comment: This answer is pretty complete; has several that are not listed in [Serebii](http://www.serebii.net/sunmoon/pokedexquests.shtml). Serebii also listed the rewards and screenshots, just in case anyone want to know them.

Answer (score 1):

There is missing one in Akala Island in which you could do many times: you need to make 6 Pyukumuku leave Hano beach. You do not battle them, tho.